# Expected value of $XY^2$ or $Cov(X,Y^2)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, covariance

I wanted to find the solution to $E[XY^2]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with given mean and variance. How can I find $Cov(X,Y^2)$?

Comment: Do you know anything more about $X$ and $Y$? If all you know is their mean and variance, you won’t be able to calculate the expectation.

Comment: What else do I need? I know that they are normally distributed

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ correlated? Is their joint distribution bivariate normal?

Comment: Yes. They do, otherwise it would be too easy

Comment: It would be nice if I could get the same formule as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889402/covariance-of-two-squared-not-zero-mean-random-variables

But for Cov(X,Y^2)

Comment: Similar: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/352110/119261.